# access query for multiple records

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have only just started using access (complete novice!!), but what i need is a way to query a database to produce multiple records. 
Maybe some back ground will be useful, I have created a table that stores details of cabling between customers, each cable has a unique ID, the table has the a-end details and B-end details of the cables, some customers may have 1 set cables others may have up to 10. How do i create a query (or maybe a report) that i can enter a customer name or if known the cable ID and it brings up details of the cabling they have installed?

Comment: Could you post an example of your schema, eg `{id, customer_name, a_location, b_location}`?

Comment: Schema is as follows

Comment: Schema is as follows: Customer_Name, Site_name,Data_Hall, Cross_Connect, Cable_Information_Ref , Telco_Circuit Ref, A_End_Customer Name, A_End_ Rack, A_End_Trunk ID, A_End_Patch Panel_Position, A_End_Port, A_End_ ODF_ Ref, A_End_ODF_tray A_End_ODF_port ref, B_End_Customer Name, B_End_Rack, B_End_Trunk ID, B_End_Patch_Panel_Position, B_End_Port, B_End_ODF Ref, B_End_ODF_tray, B_End_ODF-port ref

Comment: adding to my original post, the output i am looking for is if i query the customer; all the records for that customer.....hope i make sense

Comment: I assume those records are split across different tables? E.g. that there's a table for customers and a table for cables?

Comment: Ive put them all on the one table...do i have to split them in to two tables...it was imported across from an excel spreadsheet I was keeping updated

Comment: Look into the second form of database normalization.  Basically you shouldn't have repeating information over rows.  You shouldn't be listing out all of the customer information for every item they order and only storing it once.